# Call to a member function find() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\simplehtmldom\index.php on line 13

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping

I want to extract the data from another site for updated as per that site of data in my site but the above error shown in code and my code is as below:-

```
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file("http://www.nepalstock.com/companydetail.php");

$table = $html->find('table[width="386"]');

$i = 0;
$data = array();
foreach ($table[0]->find('tr') as $tr) {<!--this is my line 13-->
$i++;
 if ($i == 1 || $i == 2) continue;
$td = $tr->find('td');
array_push($data, array(
'listed_share' => trim($td[0]->plaintext),
'paid_up_value' => trim($td[1]->plaintext),
'total_paid_Up_Value' => trim($td[2]->plaintext),
'closing_market_price' => trim($td[3]->plaintext),
  ));
}
 $html->clear();
unset($html);

if (empty($data)) exit('No data !!!');
print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: you have using three time find() function in your code. Please can you tell me on which line its give error??

Comment: which content are you after anyway?

Comment: I would comment the line where my error occur .

Comment: Nepal stock exchange data

Comment: @paucha i mean by which specific content? inside market information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error generally occurs when you are playing with an object that does not actually exist. Try to change your code as below and remember to keep this coding behavior specially when you are working with foreign content:

```
 if (!empty($html){
     $table = $html->find('table[width="386"]');
     if(!empty($table)){
         ...
```